# 「Simple DHT というライブラリはすでに存在します。」と表示されているのに「指定されたフォルダ/ZIPファイルには有効なライブラリがありません」とエラー

Tags: arduino

「Simple DHT というライブラリはすでに存在します。」と表示されているのにzip形式のライブラリをインストールすると「指定されたフォルダ/ZIPファイルには有効なライブラリがありません」とエラーになります
Arduino IDE でUNO3を動かしています

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、このままだとどういう状況で表示されたエラーなのか分からず、第三者が問題を再現するのが難しそうです。タクミさんの作業手順の箇条書きや、OSやArduinoの種類、そもそも何で開発しているかなどの環境情報など、第三者が問題を再現するのに役立ちそうな情報を何でも追記してみてください。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できます。ヘルプセンターの[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)も参考になりそうです。

Answer (score 0):

[Arduino の開発環境に ZIP形式のライブラリをインストールできない場合の対処方法](http://softcommu-blog.com/?eid=16)　の記事が参考になるのではないかと思います。